# AttributeError when attempting to deploy gunicorn with HTTPS

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am attempting to deploy my server using Gunicorn over https. However, no matter what nginx configuration I use, I always get an attribute error in Gunicorn. I don't think the problem lies with Nginx though, but with gunicorn. But I don't know how to fix it. Here is the command I'm using to start my server:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --certfile=/etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt --keyfile=/etc/ssl/server.key pyhub2.wsgi
```

And here is my nginx configuration file:

```
  server {
    # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
    listen 80;
    server_name www.xxxxx.co;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf";
  }

  server {
    # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
    server_name www.xxxx.co;
    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log;
    location /xxxx.txt {
        root /home/bitnami;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
    location /status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log   off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }
    # PageSpeed
    #pagespeed on;
    #pagespeed FileCachePath /opt/bitnami/nginx/var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
    #  Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed
    #  handler and no extraneous headers get set.
    #location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
    #location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
    #location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
    #location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
    #location /ngx_pagespeed_message { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/PyHub2/static/;
    }
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
        allow 96.241.66.109;
        deny all;
    }
    location /robots.txt {
        root /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/PyHub2;
    }

  include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf";
  }
```

The following is the error that I get whenever attempting to connect:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.run()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 119, in run
    self.run_for_one(timeout)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 66, in run_for_one
    self.accept(listener)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 30, in accept
    self.handle(listener, client, addr)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 141, in handle
    self.handle_error(req, client, addr, e)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 213, in handle_error
    self.log.exception("Error handling request %s", req.uri)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'uri'
[2015-12-29 22:12:26 +0000] [1887] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1887)
[2015-12-30 03:12:26 +0000] [1921] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1921
```

And my wsgi per request of Klaus D.
    """
    WSGI config for pyhub2 project.

```
It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pyhub2.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Please try to find the full error traceback in your logs and add it to your post.

Comment: ...and what's in `pyhub2.wsgi`?

Comment: @KlausD. my django project.

Comment: How about posting the code?

Comment: The code for what? My django settings? I could, but there's a lot of private information in there.

Comment: I believe @DorianDore meant the code in your pyhub2.wsgi file.

Comment: I added it, but I'm certain that file is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If nginx is handling the SSL negotiation and gunicorn is running upstream, you shouldn't need to pass `--certfile=/etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt --keyfile=/etc/ssl/server.key` when launching gunicorn.

You might try a Nginx configuration to the tune of:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.xxxxx.co;

    # Redirect to SSL
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf";
}

server {  
    # Listen for SSL requests
    listen 443;
    server_name www.xxxx.co;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;


    client_max_body_size 4G;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log;

    location /xxxx.txt {
        root /home/bitnami;
    }

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/PyHub2/static;
    }

    location /admin {
        include proxy_params;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Proxy to upstream app_server
        proxy_pass http://app_server;

        allow 96.241.66.109;
        deny all;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        root /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/PyHub2;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @app_proxy;
    }

    location @app_proxy {
        # Handle requests, proxy to SSL
        include proxy_params;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Proxy to upstream app_server
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf";
}
```

Also, you might try launching gunicorn with the `--check-config` flag to check for configuration errors outside of SSL, and ensure that you're able to access :8000 locally without SSL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! When I used your code, instead of doing what it should, it just redirects me to https://127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hey Dorian, I edited my answer and included a full nginx configuration based off your sample. When you say it redirects to 127.0.0.1, is it successfully accessing Django but not via SSL? What's in "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf"?